# ASP.NET Core разработка приложения на машине с Linux под JB Rider

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, archlinux, rider

Имею:
IDE: JB Rider 2019.3

OS: EndeavourOS(Arch Linux)

dotnet 2.2

При попытке запустить пустой ASP.NET Core проект появляется ошибка:

> ```
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
>   Unable to start Kestrel.
> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found.
> To generate a developer certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https'. To trust the certificate (Windows and macOS only) run 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust'.
> For more information on configuring HTTPS see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=848054. 
>  at 
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ListenOptionsHttpsExtensions.UseHttps(ListenOptions listenOptions, Action`1 configureOptions) 
> at 
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.AddressesStrategy.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context)
> at 
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindAsync(IServerAddressesFeature addresses, KestrelServerOptions serverOptions, ILogger logger, Func`2 createBinding)
> at 
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> ```

Как я понял dotnet ругается на сертификаты и поэтому я создал самоподписанный ssl-сертификат для localhost, но это не решило проблему.

**Как исправить эту ошибку?**

P.S. Касательно ОСи - решения для ubuntu принимаются. Я попробую их адаптировать под свою ОСь.

P.S.S. Так же в выхлопе есть такая строчка:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found.
To generate a developer certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https'. To trust the certificate (Windows and macOS only) run 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust'.
```

Сделать то, что они просят я не могу. Терминал ругается на то, что данная утилита не установлена, но она была благополучно установлена...
[image: O_o]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это можно попробовать исправить так (скорее всего у вас tools находятся не в PATH):

1. Удалите `dotnet tool uninstall --global dotnet-dev-certs`.
2. Установите заново `dotnet tool install --global dotnet-dev-certs`, оно вам скорее всего выведет, что у вас тулы находятся не в PATH. Например:

```
Tools directory '/root/.dotnet/tools' is not currently on the PATH environment variable.
If you are using bash, you can add it to your profile by running the following command:

cat << \EOF >> ~/.bash_profile
# Add .NET Core SDK tools
export PATH="$PATH:/root/.dotnet/tools"
EOF

You can add it to the current session by running the following command:

export PATH="$PATH:/root/.dotnet/tools"

You can invoke the tool using the following command: dotnet-dev-certs
Tool 'dotnet-dev-certs' (version '2.2.0') was successfully installed.
```

3. `export PATH="$PATH:/root/.dotnet/tools"` (только с правильным адресом)
4. `dotnet dev-certs https`

Comment: А какую переменную на этот счёт нужно посмотреть? Она в системе так и называется PATH? Заранее прошу прощения за глупый вопрос, но на момент написания комментария я нахожусь не за компьютером.

Comment: Да, `PATH`, используя `echo $PATH` или `env`

Comment: да, тот который был выведен командой для установки `dotnet-dev-certs` в моем случае это root, у вас скорее всего будет что-то `/home/<username>/.dotnet/tools`