# C# принудительно доверенные сертификаты для Arch Linux

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, archlinux, grpc

**ПРЕДЫСТОРИЯ:**

Однажды я спрашивал каким образом можно создать сертификаты под Arch Linux для разработки на .NET Core. Мне дали ответ в [этом треде](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1066304/asp-net-core-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81-linux-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4-jb-rider).

Спустя кучу времени я понял, что хочу потрогать GRPC и микросервисы и упёрся в то, что эти самые сертификаты, созданные по гайдлайну не работают.

Не работают они так, как указано [вот тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/grpc/troubleshoot?view=aspnetcore-3.1#call-a-grpc-service-with-an-untrustedinvalid-certificate).

После того, как я прочитал справку по grpc на сайте Microsoft, я понял, что вся проблема в том, что сертификаты должны быть принудительно доверенными.

После гугла я понял, что надо было сделать `dotnet dev-certs https --trusted`, но его в линукс-версии dotnet не сделали. Снова погуглив я начал делать свои сертификаты. Делал утилитой easyrsa3, но эти сертификаты по каким-то причинам не понравились. Делал свои руками - та же история.

**ВОПРОС:**

Как сделать сертификаты для разработки в arch linux так, чтобы они были доверенными?

**ПРИ ЭТОМ:**

1. я знаю про то, что grpc можно попробовать заставить не проверять подлинность сертификатов, но во-первых это не сработало(возможно я где-то ошибся), а во-вторых, что-то мне подсказывает, что подобный случай будет не единственным и подобные проблемы будут встречаться и дальше в других кейсах.
2. Решение желательно выдавать именно для Arch Linux. Причина сугубо субъективная, но тем не менее там свежие пакеты и AUR, что в совокупе сильно упрощает жизнь.
3. Я не уверен на 100%, но как я понял, Kestrel'у в остальных случаях так же, как и в конкретном данном достаточно подсунуть адрес сертификата в формате *.pfx в appsettings.json.

UPD: 10.02.2021

Сделал сертификат и пытаюсь теперь скормить его Kestrel'у. Клиент отказывается работать с сервером, продолжая ссылаться на кривой сертификат, незащищённое соединение.

Содержание appsettings.json:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Kestrel": {
    "EndpointDefaults": {
      "Protocols": "Http2"
    },
    "Certificates": {
      "Default": {
        "Path": "/home/marko/Certs/devcerts/debug-server.pfx",
        "Password": ""
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы клиентское приложение начало нормально работать (с кастомными сертификатами) вам нужно:

**Создать CA (Certificate Authority) сертификаты:**

Это можно сделать разными способами, напрямую через `openssl`, с использованием `easy-rsa` (рекомендую), гайдов как это делать достаточно много, но в итоге у вас должно получиться два файла `*.key` и `*.crt` (в формате PEM).

**Создать сертификат для сервера, который будет подписан вашим CA:**

Аналогично с предыдущим пунктом, только это уже будет сертификаты, которые будут использоваться в вашем сервере (`Kestrel`).

**Добавить CA в список доверенных на клиентской системе:**

```
sudo trust anchor --store <путь_к_CA_crt>
```

После этого ваша система начнет доверять всем сертификатам, которые были выданы/подписаны вашим CA.

Если потому нужно будет удалить, то можно:

```
sudo trust anchor --remove <путь_к_CA_crt>
```

**Настроить Kestrel:**

Тут нужно скормить созданные сертификаты и пароль в `Kestrel`, через переменные окружения или `appsettings.json`. Тут главное сконвертировать ваши серверные `crt/key` в `pfx` (из `PEM` в `PKСS#12 формат`), т.к. будут исключения (возможно `Kestrel` можно настроить и на использование `crt/key`, но я этого не знаю).

Например так:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out server.pfx -inkey server.key -in server.crt
```

Также, возможно есть способ использовать сертификат, который был создан `dev-certs` (чтобы не создать собственный CA и сертификаты), но пока оно не работает (возможно связано с [багом](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55485511/how-to-run-dotnet-dev-certs-https-trust)).

В случае с реальными сертификатами все эти действия не понадобятся, т.к. клиентская система и так будет доверять CA.

Comment: Всё сделал, сертификат скормил, но проблема осталась. Предполагаю, что неправильно делаю что-то в appsettings.json

в его конец я добавил это:

`"Certificates": {
      "Default": {
        "Path": "/home/marko/Certs/devcerts/debug-server.pfx",
        "Password": "********"
      }
    }`

Comment: @JohnnyRage а вы его добавили в блок `Kestrel` в `appsettings.json` или просто в конец?

Comment: да, он там. Сейчас покажу содержание файлика апдейтом вопроса.